# modx getResources tv

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-getresources

I have a page for a sports club based on ModXCMS 2.1.4.
For a list of sport classes I have appr. 30 Documents for the different.
Each of this has template variables like abteilung, Wochentag, Startzeit, etc.
The tv.Wochentag contains Montag,Dienstag,Mittwoch,Donnerstag,Freitag,Samstag,Sonntag as weekdays.

Now my problem:
The output is not sorted by the variable. 
Here my code:

```
[[getResources? 
&parents=`19`
&debug=`1` 
&tvFilters=`abteilung==[[*abteilung]]`
&sortby=`{tv.Wochentag:"Montag,Dienstag,Mittwoch,Donnerstag,Freitag,Samstag,Sonntag":"ASC",tv.UhrzeitStart:"ASC"}`
&tpl=`snipSportangebot` 
&includeTVs=`1` 
&tvPrefix=`` 
&limit=`0`
&processTVs=`1`]]
```

Finaly I would like to sort by Wochentag (Weekday) and StartZeit (Starttime/Time).
What have I done wrong?
Has anyone any hint on this.

Thanks in advance

Christian

Comment: Did you really mean version 2.1.4? If so, that's 4 or 5 years old. You are missing loads of improvements, bug fixes and security patches and I think your first order of business would be to upgrade the MODX version.

Comment: Uh, Sorry. Actually it is 2.3.1 which is quite old but not that old :)

Answer (score 0):

Join `weekday` and `starttime` to one TV - Input Type: **Date**, then you will be able to sorting by TV in `getResources`:

```
sortbyTV - Template Variable to sort by
sortdirTV - Order which to sort by when using sortbyTV
sortbyTVType - Specify the data type of the sortby TV. Possible values are string, integer, decimal, datetime
```

https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources

Comment: how to join the 2 TVs?

Comment: Instead of using first TV with days and second TV with time - use one date TV. Look here: https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/commonly-used-template-tags/date-formats for formats you can take from this type of TV.

Answer (score 0):

Youy cannot sort by a TV using sortby [see the docs] if you try to use sortbyTV & sortdirTV it's going to sort them alphabetically for you.

set your day of the week tvs values to numeric :

Montag==0||Dienstag==1||Mittwoch==2||Donnerstag... etc

then your sortbyTV & sortdirTV  should behave as expected